# write node.js server with typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I want to make node.js server with typescript

```
///<reference path="definitions/node.d.ts" />
///<reference path="core/p_routing.ts" />

class server{
    private _port = 1337;
    private _host = '127.0.0.1';

    constructor(){
        require("node-ts");

        var http = require('http');

        http.createServer(function (req, res) {
            new pMVC.p_routing(req, res);
        }).listen(this._port, this._host);
        console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
    }
}

var serverw = new server();
```

this is my server.js

```
module pMVC {
    export class p_routing {
        private _url:string[];
        private _defaultController:string = 'home';
        private _defaultMethod:string = 'index';
        private _fs = null;

        public constructor(request, response) {
            response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
            response.end('Hello World\n');
        }
    }
}
```

this is my routing class. (will be routing class)

I don't have any errors in editor. but when I'm trying to visit web-site, server dies and I have following errors:

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't you `require()` the `pMVC` module in order to access it?

Comment: When I'm requiring, require('pMVC')

I have error: can't find module pMVC

Comment: You may be interested in [this](https://github.com/eknkc/typescript-require), then.

Comment: This issue is coming up daily at the moment - please don't mix internal and external modules.

Answer (score 2):

In the absence of any root level `import` / `export` the typescript compiler assumes everything is in a global name scope.

This is not true in Node.js runtime and you should use `commonsjs` modules using the `import` / `require` keywords. More : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0&hd=1

PS: I recommend using external modules even for non-nodejs projects : https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/out.md